# How to Build Multi Tenant SAAS Application using Asp.Net Core and Angular based on Microservices (Using Clean Architecture for every service)

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, multi-tenant, saas, clean-architecture

I have to build a Small Application **Software As Services** (***SAAS Multi-Tenant Single database per Tenant***) application based on Microservices SAAS architecture using **ASP.Net Core 3 and Angular with Material**

**My Understanding About Architecture or How I am planning to build**

**1)** I will develop a number of individual projects (Microservices) based on clean architecture using this template https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders.

**2)** I Have to write API gateway Web API  as a Separate project as in this link https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers. reference app and then I have to configure all individual projects (Microservices) in this gateway app.

**3)** Then I build an Angular Client project to access these individual projects (Microservices) through API gateway.

1. but how to implement this without containers and dockers?
2. And also is this the right approach?
3. How to combine all these individual projects (Microservices) in one project?

Comment: Why without containers? I mean they will save you time in the long run. Also before you start something massive, think of a simple scenario make 2 simple hello worlds applications. And make them communicate with one another based on the projects you mentioned (excellent choice of projects). Also about the right approach is highly dependent on what you want achieve. Generally a multi tenant SAAS means with a different DB for each tenant means you have to deploy dynamically extra DB so container generally help to solve this issue. Also about the last part you usually don't combine.

Comment: The example you have shown is multi tenant microservices SaaS app where each microservices talks to it's own database. I hope you are aware of complexities and cost associated with Single database per tenant approach. Without container it would be very hard to manage your services. Each project will be a services that is being served using container.  If you don't want to use container then serverless is another approach.

Comment: Yes Imran Arshad & A_Kat I need to implement fist simple hello world application to understand concepts using container and without container approach.